# How to show this integral function is not continuous

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, functions, continuity

I have to show that the following function is not continuous on $[0,\infty)$:
$I(x)=\int_{0}^{\infty}xe^{-xt}dt.$

I have shown that the integral exists for all $x \geq 0$, but how would I disprove the continuity of this function? I know the theorem that states the uniform limit of a continuous sequence of functions is continuous but not sure whether to apply that (or how) or another theorem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Let $I(x)=\int_{0}^{\infty} xe^{-tx}dt$. Then  $I(x)=-e^{-tx}|_0^{\infty}=1$ for all $x>0$ and  $I(0)=0$ by definition. Hence $I$ is not continuous.  It has a jump discontinuity at $0$.

Comment: @gillian_evans_222 I have edited my answer.

Comment: How does this show I(x) is not continuous? Is this because there's the sudden jump at x=0 from 0 to 1?

Comment: Yes, exactly. @gillian_evans_222

Comment: perfect thank you! can't believe I didn't spot this